# htaccess to redirect from domain with sub-directory url to the same url on sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have problem of redirecting from domain with sub-directory like

```
http://mydomain.com/project/01/117q803789s92d01 or
http://mydomain.com/project/08/117t803789s92d08
```

.. etc

to always

```
http://ww2.mydomain.com/project/01/117q803789s92d01 
the other link will to 
http://ww2.mydomain.com/project/08/117t803789s92d08
```

... etc

i tried this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^project\/\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/ww2\.mydomain\.com\/project\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

but for some reason its always redirect me to wrong with missing "\" like if i try to access

```
http://mydomain.com/project/01/117q803789s92d01
```

redirect me to

```
http://ww2.mydomain.com/project01/117q803789s92d01
```

Did I miss something?!

what basically i need to just redirect from

```
http://mydomain.com/project/* whole url
```

to

```
http://ww2.mydomain.com/project/* with same whole url
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just for information the problem is solved as the htaccess script below is the right one

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^project\/\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/ww2\.mydomain\.com\/project\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

thanks